# StringBuffer find 'start' and 'end' and write anything between them

Tags: java

StringBuffer find 'start' and 'end' and write anything between them

example:

```
text1
text2
start
text3
text4
end
text5
```

can i just print out of StringBuffer text3 and text4' Text that is between 'start' and 'end'

Comment: Note that according to the docs `StringBuilder` should be preferred over `StringBuffer`, unless you need synchronization: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

Comment: thx for your answer. I need synchronization for my program becouse of this i use stringbuilder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumming you have a `StringBuffer sb` that already contains the text:

```
int start = sb.indexOf("start");
int end = sb.indexOf("end");
if (start != -1 && end != -1) {
    String fragment = sb.substring(start + "start".length(), end);
    System.out.println(fragment);
}
```

Note that this finds text between `"start"` and `"end"` as you asked for in your question. However if the text in the `StringBuffer` has line breaks, you might actually want to search for text between `"start\n"` and `"end\n"`.

Comment: You don't have to change `sb` into a `String` first.

Comment: @Colin: Correct. I just saw your comment right after updating my code (but thanks for pointing it out!)

Answer (score 4):

use indexOf(String str) method to find out the index of start & end

[Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)